# Validate if date is in between two dates - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to pull out a set of data based on a criteria of dates. If the event date does not fall between the Start and End Date, it should not be pulled into the results. IF it does fall in between those dates, It would then need to ensure that the Unique ID matches with the correct program. This would need to pull all the data associated to those particular events. All Unique ID and Program ID need to match and be pulled if it is between the Start and End Date.

[image]

End result should bunch up to the following

[image]

Comment: have you tried to filter the list?

Comment: I have tried the filter list, but it will not be able to filter properly. My data set also contains multiple of the same start dates and end dates. However, the Unique ID and Program ID are the best way to differentiate them.

Comment: can you show some code or formulas of what you have tried? at least, we need something to start... how should we know the criteria for all your filter???

Comment: Those 'Unique ID' entries don't look very unique to me.

Comment: also multiple filters can be set... right now, i don't know what the real problem is :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following formula to filter data between two date:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$4:$H$10,SMALL(IF($B$4:$B$10>=$F$13,IF($B$4:$B$10<=$F$14,ROW($B$4:$B$10)-ROW($B$3))),ROWS($B$3:B3)),COLUMNS($B$3:B$3)),"")
```

As it is a array formula. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula.

Put formula in `B17` cell (as per example of below screenshot). Then drag and fill right and down as you need. ***Make sure you applied date format manually after filling formulas*** for date columns.

[image]